# How to get dataset from Getpaged?

Tags: c#, winforms, codesmith

what is problem in this code ?

```
service.BillViewService bvs = new service.BillViewService();
db.BillView bv = new db.BillView();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = bvs.GetPaged("InvNo=" + n, null, 0, 10000, out x).ToDataSet();
```

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
  bvl2 = bvs.GetPaged(" Date = '" + Today + "' AND UserId = " + SpecUserID + "", null, 0, 1000, out x).ToDataSet(false);
```